# Rancher 2.0 Agent installation

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher

**Error on the Rancher server UI side**

> [workerPlane] Failed to bring up Worker Plane: Failed to create
>   [kubelet] container on host [ip-address]: Error response from daemon: 
>   invalid mount config: must use either propagation mode "rslave" or
>   "rshared" when mount source is within the daemon root, daemon root:
>   "/var/lib/docker", bind mount source: "/var/lib/docker", propagation: 
>   "rprivate"

Docker Version: Docker version 17.12.1-ce 
OS: Centos 7

Comment: Switch to Docker CE 17.03 and it should work

Comment: thanks it works for me i did this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing, 17.03 is the latest version of Docker officially supported by K8S/Rancher, and is the latest version from Centos repositories that will function without this error.

However, if you pull from EPEL, docker-ce-17.12.0 will also work.